# React-native app and Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native

I successfully managed to create a native component that successfully logins a user into Facebook. So, in my react-native app, I've got the access token and the userId. Now, I'd like to use Facebook SDK (for example, the Graph API) to access to some basic infos (profile name, profile picture, etc.) and to do basic things (share a post, etc.)

At this point I'm quite lost: how can I do that? Can I use the fetch API? Do I need to add some node plugin to my app (I was looking for this: https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a request like this using the fetch API where query can be something like https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=token_you_got

```
fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=token_you_got')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response))
  .catch(error => 
     this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
   }));
```

More information here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/99473/introducing-react-native-building-apps-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little late to the party but for future reference to anyone who is going to integrate with Facebook with React-Native should consider using this wrapper around the ios Facebook SDK.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

Comment: it doesnt work for me: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/10 (I am getting the same issue with react-native-cli @0.1.4 and react-native-fbsdk @0.0.5)

Comment: It is tricky to install and the installation instructions could be a little better, but just make sure all instructions are followed exactly, especially the facebook instructions on how to set up the sdk with XCode. I think thats where most have made mistakes. Once you get it working its awesome and super easy to use!